# Using 'find' on rows of a matrix without looping

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

If A is a nx by ny matrix of zeros and ones and I want to find the index of the the first and last zeros in each row. Currently I'm doing the following:

```
for ix = 1:nx
    lhs_i = find(A(ix,:) < 1,1,'first');
    rhs_i = find(A(ix,:) < 1,1,'last');
    if ~isempty(lhs_i)
        lhs(ix,k) = lhs_i;
        rhs(ix,k) = rhs_i;
    else
        lhs(ix,k) = NaN;
        rhs(ix,k) = NaN;
    end
end
```

I'm sure there is a better way that doesn't involve a loop. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) -

```
[R,C] = find(A==0);
out = zeros(size(A,1),2)
out(1:max(R),:) = [accumarray(R,C,[],@min) accumarray(R,C,[],@max)]
```

Finally, if need be, replace the `zeros` with `NaNs`, but zeros themselves look like good specifiers of invalid rows (rows without zeros).

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     3     1     3     3     4
     0     3     0     2     0
     0     0     4     4     0
     1     4     1     4     2
>> [R,C] = find(A==0);
>> out = zeros(size(A,1),2);
>> out(1:max(R),:) = [accumarray(R,C,[],@min) accumarray(R,C,[],@max)]
out =
     0     0
     1     5
     1     5
     0     0
```

---

Here's another using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`minmax`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/minmax.html) -

```
P = bsxfun(@times,A==0,1:size(A,2));
P(P==0) = nan;
out = minmax(P)
```

With this solution, `Inf/-Inf` would act as the invalid specifier.

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     0     4     0     2     2
     3     4     3     1     1
     0     4     3     1     2
     1     0     3     4     0
>> P = bsxfun(@times,A==0,1:size(A,2));
>> P(P==0) = nan;
>> minmax(P)
ans =
     1     3
  -Inf   Inf
     1     1
     2     5
```